# how to reset form fields and titles in React at following example?

Tags: reactjs

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import ContactList from './ContactList.js';
import EditContact from './EditContact.js';

export default function App() {
    const [
        contacts,
        setContacts
    ] = useState(initialContacts);
    const [
        selectedId,
        setSelectedId
    ] = useState(0);
    const selectedContact = contacts.find(c =>
        c.id === selectedId
    );

    function handleSave(updatedData) {
        const nextContacts = contacts.map(c => {
            if (c.id === updatedData.id) {
                return updatedData;
            } else {
                return c;
            }
        });
        setContacts(nextContacts);
    }
    function handleReset(){
        setContacts(() => initialContacts)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ContactList
                contacts={contacts}
                selectedId={selectedId}
                onSelect={id => setSelectedId(id)}
            />
            <hr />
            <EditContact
                key={selectedId}
                initialData={selectedContact}
                onSave={handleSave}
                onReset={ handleReset}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

const initialContacts = [
    { id: 0, name: 'Taylor', email: 'taylor@mail.com' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Alice', email: 'alice@mail.com' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@mail.com' }
];
```

**EditContact.js**

```
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function EditContact({initialData, onSave, onReset}) {
    const [name, setName] = useState(initialData.name);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(initialData.email);
    return (
        <section>
            <label>
                Name:{' '}
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
                Email:{' '}
                <input
                    type="email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
            </label>
            <button onClick={() => {
                const updatedData = {
                    id: initialData.id,
                    name: name,
                    email: email
                };
                onSave(updatedData);
            }}>
                Save
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => {
                onReset()
            }}>
                Reset
            </button>
        </section>
    );
}
```

**ContactList.js**

```
export default function ContactList({
  contacts,
  selectedId,
  onSelect
}) {
  return (
    <section>
      <ul>
        {contacts.map(contact =>
          <li key={contact.id}>
            <button onClick={() => {
              onSelect(contact.id);
            }}>
              {contact.id === selectedId ?
                <b>{contact.name}</b> :
                contact.name
              }
            </button>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}
```

This is an editable contact list. You can edit the selected contact’s details and then either press “Save” to update it, or “Reset” to undo your changes.
when I change any contact and then save that, it's ok, but my problem is when I tap on reset bottom, only the contact list changes but the form fields do not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your component `EditContact` uses its own states and there is nothing that looks if something change to change thoses states.

You can add a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (initialData) {
    setName(initialData.name);
    setEmail(initialData.email);
  }
}, [initialData])
```

But then you need also to tell your state of contacts that it is another list so in your reset do this:

```
function handleReset(){
  setContacts([...initialContacts])
}
```

Comment: but react says: You don’t need Effects to transform data for rendering.

Comment: but EditContet has its own key, when intitalData is changed then EditContet is rerenderd agian but?

Answer (score 1):

if we don't want to use **useEffect** then:

**EditContent.js**

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function EditContact({initialData, onSave, onReset}) {
    const [name, setName] = useState(initialData.name);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(initialData.email);
    const [prevData, setPrevData] = useState(initialData);

    if (initialData !== prevData) {
        setPrevData(initialData);
        setName(initialData.name);
        setEmail(initialData.email);

    }
    
    // useEffect(() => {
    //     if (initialData) {
    //         setName(initialData.name);
    //         setEmail(initialData.email);
    //     }
    // }, [initialData])

    return (
        <section>
            <label>
                Name:{' '}
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
                Email:{' '}
                <input
                    type="email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
            </label>
            <button onClick={() => {
                const updatedData = {
                    id: initialData.id,
                    name: name,
                    email: email
                };
                onSave(updatedData);
            }}>
                Save
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => {

                onReset()
                setName(initialData.name);
                setEmail(initialData.email);
                
            }}>
                Reset
            </button>
        </section>
    );
}
```